# Inserting images automatically on slides referencing model #? MICROSOFT POWERPOINT

Tags: vba, automation, powerpoint

I have about 100 slides here on powerpoint that look like this:

[Slide example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRfdU.png)

I need to insert an image into the text box on each slide with the sizing of

height = 5, width = 3.64

and positioning of:

Horizontal = 6" / Vertical = 1.2" (Both from top left corner)

For good measure, here are all of the image format settings: 
[Image format settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6kkl.png)

The image files are the same as the model number, such as MHS1306.jpg.

Is there any way to use a macro to automatically reference the model number, insert the corresponding image, and then resize it to the correct size?

All of the images are in the same folder.

The image just needs to be in that position, the text box isn't important, just shows where the image should go.

I am very new to VBA and scripts, and basically know nothing about it yet, so I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: This page on my PPT FAQ site will get you started with code to insert a picture and size/position it:  Batch Insert a folder full of pictures, one per slide
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00352_Batch_Insert_a_folder_full_of_pictures-_one_per_slide.htm

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I'll check that out. Before you replied a ended up pasting each image individually on 100+ slides then using your thor tool to resize them.

Comment: Aha, you found Thor ... well done.  It's quite new (but based on part of another add-in that's been around for years).  Glad it helped.